# Reducing the file size of js data file for qgis2web

Tags: qgis, leaflet, javascript, qgis2web

I created a map using QGIS and I used QGIS2Web and leaflet to export it and put it on website. I was able to publish all the files except for a JavaScript file, which holds the spatial data. The reason that I was not able to publish it is that the size of the JavaScript file is a bit over the maximum file size we are allowed to publish (in other words putting online). The size of the file is currently 7.8 mb, however we are not allow to publish files bigger than 6.9 mb. What would be the best way to reduce its size (if possible without losing quality)?

The name of the JavaScript file is "dza_admbnda_adm2_unhcr2020_0". Below is a sample of the data.

```
var json_dza_admbnda_adm2_unhcr2020_0 = {"type":"FeatureCollection","name":"dza_admbnda_adm2_unhcr2020_0","crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}},"features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"ADM0_EN":"Algeria","ADM1_EN":"Adrar","ADM2_EN":"Adrar","Language":null},"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-0.170986310342979,27.769729613624808],[-0.17085541772124,27.772535324086906],[-0.175043553120319,27.778894424183765],[-0.198539569688157,27.799701691341703],[-0.204244122372273,27.803136825767396],[-0.218795805895585,27.81448745682286],[-0.223506688924814,27.816490173076563],[-0.237054958767323,27.825489043692485],[-0.27199205803257,27.852769851778895],[-0.279978274944499,27.855691910058187],[-0.284692079295023,27.859359741084589],[-0.287653655005173,27.857295989659196],[-0.302752793422203,27.857469559266331],[-0.302804440262827,27.855579376259474],[-0.311727523659279,27.855352402165657],[-0.311810464211157,27.853746413843457],[-0.317508160953025,27.853460311808313],[-0.322621852148907,27.849851608251434],[-0.33751896035685,27.863092422316388],[-0.33284929382948,27.876098632717333],[-0.316778331886976,27.894144058211193],[-0.331683516847622,27.98978233321467],[-0.333302498381897,27.99969482404855],[-0.303586601584085,28.064096450837873],[-0.246851264807072,28.088842391763993],[-0.068490483074152,28.167325974019743],[-0.103061594319577,28.01135635374051],[-0.098380974633964,27.998636246313872],[-0.121827446418919,27.831949234297095],[-0.170986310342979,27.769729613624808]]]]}},
```

Comment: In what format are data in your JavaScript file?

Comment: I believe they are in JSON format. I added a sample of it above.

Comment: There are at least two things you can do. First, reduce the number of decimals. Precision to 15 decimals means precision to 110 pm (pico meters). If you need cm precision, 7 decimals is enough. Second, you can ZIP your data, which will further reduce the size.

Comment: I might first go with zipping the data. I have so many coordinates and It might take a while reduce the number of decimals for all of them. By zipping the data, do you mean zipping the js file?

Comment: Better be only GeoJSON.

Comment: Reduce precision and minify when running gis2web https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web#data-export

Comment: @user2856 I followed what you recommended. The file is now 64.6 MB. The server I am using allows the maximum of 50 mb. Is there a way to further reduce the file size?